# generate json array with two data values

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, ajax, arrays

please advice me how to get the results of both values 'content' and 'categories' on below json array.. currently it give results only for 'content'

```
     $abc=$_GET["term"];

$query=mysql_query("
SELECT  b.title as category ,a.title as content 
FROM  tb_content a, tb_categories b
WHERE ( b.title like '%".$abc."%' 
OR a.title like '%".$abc."%')
AND a.categories_id=b.id
AND b.parent_id=81
");
$json=array();
    while($display=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
         $json[]=array(
                    'value'=> $display["content"],
                    'label'=>$display["content"],

                        );
```

Comment: could it be because you are sending content twice rather than content and category?

Comment: @Kevin B : i want to show the results related to both content and category. do you think i should put content on first and category on second , is it ?

Comment: Where within your array do you want to display the category? Why do you need both value and label if they both contain the same content?

Comment: @Kevin B : b.title as category => this shows category name where as  a.title as content => this shows catagory data.  iwant both to display. please advice

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

1. You always should escape variables before using them in a query.
2. You are not closing your while loop.
3. You are using the same key for value and label.
4. Remove the last comma in the while loop.
5. Follow my code:

   ```
    $abc = mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET["term"] );

    $query = mysql_query("
                    SELECT  b.title as category ,a.title as content 
                    FROM  tb_content a, tb_categories b
                    WHERE ( b.title like '%".$abc."%' 
                    OR a.title like '%".$abc."%')
                    AND a.categories_id=b.id
                    AND b.parent_id=81
                   ");
     $json = array();

     while ( $display = mysql_fetch_array($query) )
     {
         $json[]=array(
               'value' => $display["content"],
               'label' => $display["category"]
         );
      }

    //output:

    print_r($json); //as an array

    echo json_encode($json); // as a json string
   ```